# XAML WP8 - ScrollViewer doesnt take into account orientation

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

Im working on an app for Win Phone 8 and need to make a settings screen.
I created a user control for this.

...omitted the beginning stuff...

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Opacity="0.995" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ScrollViewer
        Name="scrollViewer"
        Margin="0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Background="#CC000000" Opacity="0.995" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0">
            <RichTextBox x:Name="MenuLabel" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="[Menu]"/>
                </Paragraph>
            </RichTextBox>
```

I have all my setting options in the stack panel.
While im in portait orientation, everything works fine, listed correctly, scrolls correctly by swiping upward from the bottom of the phone to the top. However, when I rotate the phone to landscape orientation, the control shows correctly but the swiping remains the same. So instead on swiping up from one side to the other, I still need to swipe from the bottom of the phone to the top -- essentially swiping right to left to make the control scroll up.

Am I missing something? Did I forget a setting somewhere? Ive scoured the internet for any clues / advice and could not find anything relevant.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
-G

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question/problem. Do you need to swipe from right to left in landscape orientation (all contols aligned horizontal) and in portait orientation you need to swipe from button and up (all controls is vertical orientated)?

Comment: When I am in Landscape orientation, things are listed out correctly, its a vertical list, but the swiping to scroll down the list acts like its still in portrait... meaning you need to swipe right to left for the list to move up.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I strongly suspect this is somehow related to VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" and HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" settings. Try to play with them a bit, maybe enable both of them and see if something changes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that earlier. 
No help, just made the scrolling odd. 
In any case, the response below solved the issue. Thanks for the help though. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the Opacity property on your ScrollViewer and your Grid, and it will work!

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer"
                  Margin="0"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                  Background="#CC000000"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Margin="0">
            <RichTextBox x:Name="MenuLabel"
                         Height="100"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="[Menu]" />
                </Paragraph>
            </RichTextBox>
```

Comment: WOW. You sir deserve a medal!
I have no idea how or why opacity would interfere... but that was the problem and removing it fixed the issue.
Thank you so much for the help!!

Comment: That is interesting indeed. +1